# Decompiling Python Files: ValueError

Tags: python, extract, pyinstaller, reverse-engineering, decompiling

So I have this python file and I successfully unpacked its content inside of it we have our file.pyc
I appended the magic bytes to it so it went from:

```
E3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

to something that looked like this:

```
42 0D 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E3 00
```

The magic bytes seem to be correct however when I try to decompile using "uncompyle6" i get this:

```
<class 'ValueError'>; bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

To solve this I went and tried out "decompyle3" however it still returned the same error.

```
Extra Info:
[*] Pyinstaller version: 2.1+
[*] Python version: 37
[*] Length of package: 21143183 bytes
[*] Found 66 files in CArchive
[*] Beginning extraction...please standby
[+] Possible entry point: pyiboot01_bootstrap
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_certifi
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_multiprocessing
[+] Possible entry point: pyi_rth_pkgres
[+] Possible entry point: KitsuneSelfbot
[*] Found 1013 files in PYZ archive
```

Also Here is the first chunk of bytes from our file.pyc (unedited):

And then from our future.pyc these are the first bytes

```
42 0D 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 F3 D8 00 00 00 64 00 5A 00 64 01 64 02 64 03 64 04 64 05 64 06 64 07 64 08 64 09 64 0A 67 0A 5A 01 64 0B 67 01 65 01 17 00 5A 02 64 0C 5A 03 64 0D 5A 04 64 0E 5A 05 64 0F 5A 06 64 10 5A 07 64 11 5A 08 64 12 5A 09 64 13 5A 0A 64 14 5A 0B 64 15 5A 0C 47 00 64 16 64 17 84 00 64 17 83 02 5A 0D 65 0D 64 18 64 19 65 03 83 03 5A 0E 65 0D 64 1A 64 1B 65 04 83 03 5A 0F 65 0D 64 1C 64 1D 65 05 83 03 5A 10 65 0D 64 1E 64 1D 65 06 83 03
```

I also tried unpacking future.pyc however it also returned this same error:

```
<class 'ValueError'>; bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Any help at all would be appreciated :)